# Getting an Error in ggplot: Invalid argument to unary operator

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, label

I am working on a plot of some data values against months.

I am using two `geom_lines()` function for each data type. I am getting the plot and everything I want, but when I try to label the x axis with "Months" I am getting an error.

```
Error in +xlab("Months") : invalid argument to unary operator
```

My code for the plot is :

```
library(ggplot2)
library(officer)

data <- "U://30-Power & Water//25 Renewables//WORK//Data//PVPlanner//PVPlanner.csv"

data <- read.table(data,skip = 36, header = T,  sep=";")

months <- c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "June", "July", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec")
data <- data.frame(months, data[1:12,2:6])
data$months <-factor(data$months,levels = c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "June", "July", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"))

plot <- ggplot(data) +geom_path(aes(x= months, y= GHId, col = "GHId", group = 1)) + geom_path( aes(x = months,y = Diffd,colour = "Diffd", group = 1) )+ scale_colour_manual("", breaks =c("GHId","Diffd"), values = c( "red","Blue"))
+xlab("Months")+ylabs("Irradiation")+ggtitle("Global and Diffuse horizontal irradiance")
plot
```

And my data looks like this:

```
  GHId GHIm Diffd Diffm  T24
1     3.27  101  0.92    29 13.3
2     3.92  110  1.23    34 13.3
3     5.30  164  1.58    49 13.9
4     6.18  185  1.89    57 14.9
5     6.93  215  2.00    62 16.4
6     7.53  226  1.80    54 18.4
7     7.42  230  1.87    58 21.1
8     7.06  219  1.58    49 22.0
9     5.97  179  1.39    42 21.3
10    4.50  140  1.26    39 18.7
11    3.53  106  0.99    30 15.9
12    2.90   90  0.86    27 13.3
```

there is no issue at all with the plot. I am getting error only when I try to give labels to the axis. I am not sure why this happening.

Your help will be appreciated.

Regards

Comment: The `+` should be in the preceding line (the line before `xlab`) otherwise the preceding line is terminated, and `+xlab` is read as a beginning of a new and separate command (a unary operator).

Comment: oh wow. I never though this could be an error!  It is working now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Djork Why not adding this as an answer, so this post can be marked as solved?

Comment: @luchonacho I updated as an answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For multiple layers in `ggplot2` to be evaluated together, the preceding line should end with `+` to indicate continuation to the next line, otherwise that preceding line is considered complete and terminated.

In this instance, the `+xlab` in the next line is read as a beginning of a new and separate command, and evaluated independently (a unary operator), causing the error.

The correct code is:

```
plot <- ggplot(data) +
    geom_path(aes(x= months, y= GHId, col = "GHId", group = 1)) + 
    geom_path( aes(x = months,y = Diffd,colour = "Diffd", group = 1) ) + 
    scale_colour_manual("", breaks =c("GHId","Diffd"), values = c( "red","Blue")) +
    xlab("Months") + ylabs("Irradiation") +
    ggtitle("Global and Diffuse horizontal irradiance")

plot
```